# Series of stories with titles like "The Agile Rigelian"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mutant

A series of short stories around 1950, about a guy with two brains and a perfect mind shield, and no it's not Gosseyn.  The stories had Ellery Queen-like titles such as "The Agile Rigelian".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ISFDB identifies "The Agile Algolian" (published 1954) as number 7 of the [Manning Draco series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?36175) by Kendell Foster Crossen.

Here is the complete listing of stories:

- The Merakian Miracle,
  Thrilling Wonder Stories
  10/1951
- The Regal Rigellian,
  Thrilling Wonder Stories
  02/1952
- The Polluxian Pretender,
  Thrilling Wonder Stories
  10/1952
- The Caphian Caper,
  Thrilling Wonder Stories
  12/1952
- Whistle Stop in Space,
  Thrilling Wonder Stories
  08/1953
- Mission to Mizar,
  Thrilling Wonder Stories
  11/1953
- The Agile Algolian,
  Thrilling Wonder Stories,
  WTR54